# ansible synchronize module validate files

Tags: ansible

We have an ansible to manage our Prometheus server, We use the copy module to copy the alert templates to the destination and check their syntax using `promtool` command:

```
- name: copy custom alerting rule files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ prometheus_configuration_directory }}/rules/"
    owner: root
    group: '{{prometheus_group}}'
    mode: '0640'
    validate: "{{ prometheus_binary_directory }}/promtool check rules %s"
  with_fileglob: "rules/*.yml"
  notify:
    - reload prometheus
```

But what if we want to remove an alert file from the Prometheus server? We end up with the `synchronize` module of ansible to sync our file with the Prometheus server, but now we cannot use `validate` to validate the rules, is there any other way to handle this task?